Framer animation on state change only working first change
I am trying to animate Framer motion.div every time my state changes.  I have try using key={data.results} but this isn't working.  The animation works but only on the first state change. I appreciate any help you can give me.
<Results>
      <ul className="date-buttons horizontal" onChange={onChange}>
        {months.map((month, i) => {
          i++;
          return (
            <Link
              className="month"
              activeClassName="active"
              onClick={() => getByDate(i)}
            >
              {month}
            </Link>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      <motion.ul
        key={data.results}
        initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
        exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
        transition={{ duration: 0.75 }}
        className="results-ul horizontal"
      >
        {data.results.length > 0
          ? data.results.map((book) => {
              return <Card book={book}></Card>;
            })
          : null}
      </motion.ul>
    </Results>

I have tried using key inside motion.div.  I am expecting the animation every time I get new api results.
